# How to access subfolder in htdocs in apache server with react

Tags: reactjs, apache, build, htdocs

When I build some app on react and put in htdocs everything work fine.

I create a folder with name "todo" in htdocs and paste build files in the second react project and when I want to access this folder localhost/todo/ I cannot see the project.

Can I get some hint how to fix that ?

Comment: There might be some problem with regards to your build routes. In some cases, react app routing only works on the root domain of ```localhost```. It means that you have to paste your build file directly to the ```htdocs``` folder and adding an additional folder would mess up the routing of the app.

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `basename` in your `Router` and build the app again.

```
<Router basename={'/todo'}>
  <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
  <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/news`} component={News} />
  <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/about`} component={About} />
</Router>
```

You may refer to [this link](https://medium.com/@zero2603/how-to-deploy-reactjs-app-into-subdirectory-with-webpack-58d5ce32c655) to fully change your webpack routes.